# TemplateSyntaxError at / 'xxx' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
... admin_list, admin_modify, admin_urls, cache, i18n, l10n, log, static, tz
```

I have problems with creating a custom tag. I followed the instructions on the official Django documentation. I also copied the code but still get this error.

The file it contains the tag is xxx.py that is in the templatetags dir. Is in app's root directory:

```
app/
   migrations
   static
   template
   templatetags
   __init.py__
   admin.py
   apps.py
   models.py
   ....etc
```

The tag in xxx.py:

```
from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

The code in template index.html

```
{% load xxx %}
{% current_time "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p" %}
```

The traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 3.1.5
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['auctions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\paren\OneDrive\Documenti\Programmazione\copia progetti corso harvard\CS50\project2\commerce\commerce\auctions\templates\auctions\index.html, error at line 1
   'xxx' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
   1 :  {% load xxx %} 
   2 : 
   3 : 
   4 : {% block body %}
   5 : {% if message %}
   6 :     <div class="alert">{{message}}</div>
   7 : {% endif %}
   8 : <div class="main">
   9 : <h2>Active listings</h2>
   10 : 
   11 : {% for ele in msg%}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1034, in find_library
    return parser.libraries[name]

During handling of the above exception ('xxx'), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\paren\OneDrive\Documenti\Programmazione\copia progetti corso harvard\CS50\project2\commerce\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 17, in index
    return render(request,"auctions/index.html",{'msg':qs})
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 15, in get_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1091, in load
    lib = find_library(parser, name)
  File "C:\Users\paren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 1036, in find_library
    raise TemplateSyntaxError(

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: 'xxx' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

Comment: Did you create an `__init__.py` file in your `templatetags` folder? Also make sure you have added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: the app's name is 'auctions'. is the first in the list INSTALLED_APPS. also the file __init__.py it's at own place

Answer (score 0):

In your project folder name of the template is not in the plural form so, you need to change it to **templates** because by default Django have this naming convention while creating a project

Comment: But the filters work. They are hosted in the same directory as the Tags. If there is an error in the directory name, the filters shouldn't work either, right?

Comment: I was also facing the same issue TemplateSyntexError than I did this that's why I suggest that